# Total derivative in high dimension

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I recently came to know the process of differentiating in high dimensions and also the chain rule in this situation. Consider a function $g:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ as $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2-1 $. Now, we observe that $g(x,y)=g(-x,-y)$. We totally differentiate both sides with respect to the vector $(x,y)$. $LHS$ becomes $Dg_{(x,y)}=(2x,2y)$ and for $RHS$, we define $h:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ as $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$. $RHS$ is $g\circ h(x,y)$, so we apply chain rule and get $$Dg\circ h_{(x,y)}=Dg_{h(x,y)} \cdot Dh_{(x,y)}$$
$$=(-2x,-2y)\times\left(\begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{matrix}\right)$$
$$=(2x,2y)$$

So, we evaluate them to be same, as expected. But **the doubt is :**

For the case of real numbers, we have $x\mapsto x^2$, this function also satisfies the same equality but the linear map for derivative at $x=a$ is $x\mapsto 2ax$ and that for $x=-a$ is $x\mapsto -2ax$?

So, why aren't they same in this situation? Have I done some wrong calculation for high dimensional case? If yes, then can't we differentiate both sides in high dimensional case?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situations you describe are not the same. In the first case, you are taking the derivative of two functions: $g$ and $\widetilde{g}=g \circ h$ and concluding that they are equal at every point. (Which, as you say, is natural.)

In the second case, you are considering the derivative of a function in two different points. If you do the same for the original function $g$, you will find similarly that $Dg_{a}=-Dg_{-a}$, which does not contradict anything.

Likewise, if you put $f:x \mapsto x^2$ and $g: x \mapsto f(-x)$, you will find that the derivative is the same at every point, which would be the similar thing to do with respect to the first case.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 0):

you get mixed up: 
 the derivativ of f(x,y) ar (a.b) ist (2a,2b) at (-a,-b) it is (-2a.-2b) the negativ of ((2a,2b9 the same at f(x)=x^2 f'(a)=2a, f'(-a)=-2a
so you have the same behavior in 2d as in 1d.
trula